# Find and Rename large quantities of files

Tags: powershell, copy, file-rename

I am using PowerShell to find, move, and rename a large amount of audit files. These files are in a shared folder with hundreds of gigabytes of extra junk. Manually clicking and dragging would take hours or even days as they are in many nested folders.

All files are currently named the same (audit.log, or audit1.log if there is a second log in the same folder). I need to find those files, copy them to a central location and rename them so they don't overwrite one another (not necessarily in that order).

I am not a programmer by any standard. This is what I have tried so far based on this website:

```
cd "H:\Flights\SCP\Log Analysis\1st Quarter"
Get-ChildItem -Filter "audit*.log" -Recurse `
| Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'audit', "$_.Fullname"} -WhatIf `
| Move-Item -Destination "H:\Flights\SCP\Log Analysis\Audit logs" -WhatIf
```

I use `-WhatIf` to make sure I do not make a mistake since I cannot overwrite the files. My original line of thought was to simply replace the word audit with the file path, but any reasonable method to rename the files in a way which will not overwrite will be helpful.

Comment: The `.FullName` property includes the path, which has invalid filename characters like ``\`` and possibly `:`. Prepending the file's `.Directory.Name` would probably be better. That said, `Move-Item` can move the files and give them a new filename at the same time, so you don't need `Rename-Item`. In fact, renaming while iterating could get you into trouble..

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I apologize because I have only a very shallow understanding of powershell scripting. How do I prepend the Directory.name to the filename?

Comment: So you want them all named `{something completely random}.log`? Try `Rename-Item -NewName {"$(New-Guid).log"}` :-)

Comment: Thank you! can I combine the new-guid and the move-item command? for example: Move-Item -Destination "H:\Flights\SCP\Log Analysis\Audit logs\$(New-Guid).log"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) and [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) have provided all the crucial pointers in comments:

- [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) only accepts a mere *name* as a `-NewName` argument.
- [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) can perform *both* moving *and* renaming in a single operation.
- [Delay-bind script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) (`{ ... }`) can be passed to both `Rename-Item`'s `-NewName` and `Move-Item`'s `-Destination` parameters, which enable deriving the target name / path dynamically, for each input object (`$_`)

To put it all together:

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Filter audit*.log -Recurse |
  Move-Item -Destination { 
    "H:\Flights\SCP\Log Analysis\Audit logs\$($_.FullName -replace '[:\\/]', '_')" 
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- The target *directory* of the move operation must already exist (`-Force` does *not* create it for you, it would only allow you to replace an existing file).
- `$_.FullName -replace '[:\\/]', '_'` transforms the full path of the original file into something that can be used as a file *name*, by replacing `:`, `\` (and `/`) characters with `_`.

  - The caveat is that with long paths you may run into the 256-characters-per-name limit
  - An alternative is to use an abstract, unique identifier of fixed length, which you can generate with the [`New-Guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-guid) cmdlet, as Mathias suggests.